# Replace pattern for individual characters

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, replace

I need to run a select statement that replaces individual characters in an varchar column. Each character in the column will be changed. A-Z need to change to 'A' and 0-9 need to change to '0'. I think I understand how to find them with regex, but I am not sure if the replace function can be used to do this. Examples

```
ABC123 > AAA000
Z15X97 > A00A00
```

Can this be done in tsql without using substring to change each character one at a time, or without a list (25 for letters, 8 for numbers) of statements like `replace(<column>, 'B','A')`?

Comment: Do you deal with UPPERCASE only? Might there be special characters besides the "pure plain latin A-Z"?

Comment: In my case evrything is uppercase A to Z or 0 to 9, but you make a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(TestString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('ABC123'),('Z15X97');

WITH RunningNummbers AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Inx
    FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS x(y)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS a(b)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS c(d) --1000 running numbers
)
SELECT TestString
      ,(    
        SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(tbl.TestString,Inx,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' THEN 'A' 
                    ELSE CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(tbl.TestString,Inx,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN '0' ELSE SUBSTRING(tbl.TestString,Inx,1) END
               END
        FROM RunningNummbers
        WHERE Inx<=LEN(tbl.TestString)
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS Replaced
FROM @tbl AS tbl
```

The result

```
ABC123  AAA000
Z15X97  A00A00
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way, its inefficient but hopefully this is only for a one-off

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT, txt VARCHAR(255));
INSERT tbl VALUES (1, 'ABC123'), (2, 'Z15X97'), (3, 'AZ09'), (4, '0123456789ABCXYZ')

;WITH T (id, txt, pos) AS (
    SELECT id, CAST(txt AS VARCHAR(255)), 0 FROM tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,
        CAST(STUFF(txt, pos + 1, 1, CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(txt, pos + 1, 1) LIKE '[A-Z]' THEN 'A' ELSE '0' END) AS VARCHAR(255)),
        pos + 1
    FROM T WHERE pos < LEN(txt)
)
SELECT id, txt
FROM T WHERE pos = LEN(txt)
```

---

```
id  txt
4   0000000000AAAAAA
3   AA00
2   A00A00
1   AAA000
```

Comment: Recursive CTE, nice approach, +1 from my side

Comment: Thank you both. These both work. However, I may have to resort to a simple set mycolumn = replace(mycolumn, 'B','A') and break it up into multiple set statements since I have 540m rows. :/